# Laravel. setRelation(s) - adds only the last relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

php: 7.3.4
Laravel Framework 5.7.28

Hi, everybody. Help add data for all relations.
Now for some reason it turns out that only the last relation is added.
`setRelations` works similarly.

code

```php
public static function firstOrCreateModel() {
        $cart = Cart::firstOrCreate(self::getWhereQuery());

        if ($cart->delivery === 1) {
            $cart->setRelation('np_area', $cart->with('npArea')->first());
            $cart->setRelation('np_city', $cart->with('npCity')->first());
            $cart->setRelation('np_warehouse', $cart->with('npWarehouse')->first());
            dump($cart->toArray());
        }

        return $cart;
    }
```

[Result. GIF screen recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMHck.gif)

Comment: Why do you add carts as relation to your cart?

Comment: Because depending on the value that is in the column 'delivery' I need to get information about the offices of the company that is engaged in delivery. And there is a different number of tables turned out for each company. (for example, one only area and Department = two tables, one three) And I need to look at the value in the delivery field and then take the relevant data of a particular company that will be engaged in the delivery of this order.

Comment: I do not need to enter data into the Database on the relationship. I just need to prepare the model so that it is on the front-end flew in the right form. Well, due to the fact that the offices of companies that are engaged in delivery is obtained with their api there, each has its own structure. Not everyone has the same number of tables. And I had to do this.

Comment: I understand. But with `$cart->with('npArea')->first()` you are not doing anything useful I think. `$cart` is already a `Cart` and `with('npArea')` will only eager load the relation, not select it. So the result of `$cart->with('npArea')->first()` is again an instance of `Cart` which doesn't seem what you want to set as relation? And by the way, what speaks against using `$cart->load('np_area')`?

Answer (score 1):

setRelation() does not save to the DB [setRelation](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_setRelation) its just for testing you better use sync() if its many-to-many or attach() if its one-to-many

Comment: I don't need to save any data. I need to put some Relation in the selected model. It turns out that the output of the model is only 1 Relation (the last one) instead of three.